# Problem on search function with parameter inputted is from_date and to_date, return the list of projects that have same input datetime

Tags: php, laravel

This is the problem that I am meeting with - problem on search function with parameter is `$from_date` and `$to_date` in Laravel.

I have a function `getByDate()` in ProjectRepository with the following code:

```
public function getByDate() {
    $from_date = Carbon::parse(request('startDate'))->startOfDay();
    $to_date = Carbon::parse(request('endDate'))->endOfDay();

    $project = DB::table('projects')
    ->whereBetween('startDate', [$from_date, $to_date])
    ->get();

    return $project;
}
```

From the ProjectController, I inject the repository into `searchProject()` in Controller, in this one I have:

```
public function searchProject(){
    $project = $this->repository->getByDate();

    if (is_null($project)) {
        return $this->sendError('Projects not found. Try again :)');
    }

    return response()->json([
        'status' => true,
        'data' => $project,
    ]);
}
```

In the `api.php` where I declare Route for mapping API URL, I have this line:

```
Route::get('search_project', 'Project\ProjectController@searchProject');
```

And when I test on POSTMAN with the URL `localhost:8000/api/search_project?from_date=2018-01-12&to_date=2018-03-03`, it return the result

```
"message": "",
"exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException",
"file": "D:\\project-porfolio\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteCollection.php",
"line": 179,
```

Can anyone give me some advise what I do have something wrong and suggest for another way?

Comment: Just to be sure, are you testing a *GET* request in Postman?

Comment: Yes it is correct. I am using GET request in POSTMAN

Comment: Does `localhost:8000/search_project` (without `api/`) work?  If yes, double check `RouteServiceProvider` class which is supposed to manage routes in `api.php`, and apply the `api/` prefix. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#basic-routing

Comment: withou api/ it is still return NotFoundHTTPException too. I will check the RouteServiceProvider as you said. But 1 thing weird that Route::resource('projects','Project\ProjectController'); it is still working. Why this one is not working?

Comment: protected function mapApiRoutes()
    {
        Route::prefix('api')
             ->middleware('api')
             ->namespace($this->namespace)
             ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
    }

The mapping function for api route is still working

Comment: Strange.  Does `php artisan route:list` show the route OK?

Comment: Yes, when i check, the route is still received with the same URL API i declare in api.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you are not capturing the right params from the code you have posted. So in your repository you are looking for `startDate` and `endDate`
but the url in question has `from_date=2018-01-12&to_date=2018-03-03`. I believe it should be;

```
$from_date = Carbon::parse(request('from_date'))->startOfDay();
$to_date = Carbon::parse(request('to_date'))->endOfDay();
```

PS: By the way you are using a custom action of `searchProjects()` in your ProjectsController. Its a best practice that you would create an invokable class i.e. single action controller ( if thats the only action you require ) and then have your logic there. so may be something like below;

```
// Route
Route::get('search_projects', Project\SearchProjectsController::class)

// Controller
class SearchProjectsController extends Controller 
{
    public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {
       // your logic
    }
}
```

here is a link to further explore this topic https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MF0jFKvS4SI

Comment: so i must bind with the same param same with in the request('')?

Comment: yes whatever params you pass in url; are the params that you should be accessing through the request , so you could do some thing like ```startDate=2018-01-12&endDate=2018-03-03``` and then no need to change you repository method

Comment: $startDate = Carbon::parse(request('startDate'))->startOfDay();
        $endDate = Carbon::parse(request('endDate'))->endOfDay();

I bind the same with the column name but i still meet the NotFoundHttp. It is so werid

Comment: try runing these commands ``` "composer dumpautoload -o",
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan cache:clear",
            "php artisan route:clear",
            "php artisan view:clear",
            "php artisan config:clear" ```

Comment: I have a command clear-all-cache and do composer dump-autoload and still return same error. I dont know do i need to put the $startDate and $endDate into the getByDate($startDate,$endDate). ~~

Comment: by the way do run ```dd(request()->all()``` in your controller or repository to check what you are getting

Comment: no no no i mean this is inside ProjectController, the CRUD API is working perfectly. But when i do the searchProjectByDate(), it turns out like this 404 - NotFoundHttp

Check on api.php and php artisan route:list it is already declared inside. SO i am thinking do i miss anything on declare parameter or not. That is what i am confusing

Comment: It is easy to test if the parameter names are the problem - in `searchProject()`, as the first line, simply `return request()->all();`.  If it works, you know at least the route is working.   Even if the params are wrong, I don't think this is the reason for a `NotFoundHttpException`.

Comment: I have edited the answer above and see if that helps.